# Sanity IO CMS - What is the difference between sanity.config.js and sanity.json

Tags: javascript, json, content-management-system, sanity

Working with a Version 3 Sanity project to provide backend data.

However, I noticed that there are two files that deals with project settings/configurations.

1. `PROJECT_DIR/sanity.config.js` - included from startup
2. `PROJECT_DIR/sanity.json` - not included from startup

**My question are**

1. What is the difference between the two
2. How should I handle duplicate settings such as `plugins` that are already defined in `sanity.config.js`, do I define them again in `sanity.json`?

Please help, as I cannot find any documentation that addresses my questions above,

**An example** taken from [sanity docs](https://www.sanity.io/docs/sanity-json) `sanity.json`

```
{
  "root": true,
  "project": {
    "name": "Movies",
    "basePath": "/studio"
  },
  "api": {
    "projectId": "<yourProjectID>",
    "dataset": "production"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@sanity/base",
    "@sanity/components",
    "@sanity/default-layout",
    "@sanity/default-login",
    "@sanity/desk-tool",
    "@sanity/google-maps-input"
  ],
  "parts": [
    {
      "name": "part:@sanity/base/schema",
      "path": "./schemas/schema.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

**And an example** from my project `sanity.config.js`

```
import {defineConfig} from 'sanity'
import {deskTool} from 'sanity/desk'
import {visionTool} from '@sanity/vision'
import {schemaTypes} from './schemas'

export default defineConfig({
  name: 'default',
  title: 'app-title',

  projectId: '<project-id>',
  dataset: 'production',

  plugins: [deskTool(), visionTool()],

  schema: {
    types: schemaTypes,
  },
})
```

Would I still include `"@sanity/desk-tool"` in my `sanity.json` if deskTool() is already added within the plugins array in `sanity.config.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON-based configuration in `sanity.json` file has been deprecated on Sanity v3 in favor of `sanity.config.js` file, this is one of their breaking changes. [See docs](https://www.sanity.io/docs/example-migrating-the-blog-template-from-studio-v2-to-v3#45de65f9e7e7) for reference. In other words, if you're using Sanity v3, don't include `sanity.json`, handle all the configs that were previously in that file on `sanity.config.js`.

Comment: Oh wow, totally missed it. I feel like the documentation on [https://www.sanity.io/docs/sanity-json](https://www.sanity.io/docs/sanity-json) could have done a better job of informing users that `sanity.json` is deprecated in v3. Thank you for pointing that out!